# How do we add images here in 1 single row having name of animals under their pics html css

Tags: html, css, image, notepad++

```
<ul type="disc">

<li> Himalayan/Indian Black Bear <br> 
<Img Src="http://www.shunya.net/Pictures/Himalayas/Darjeeling/HimalayanBear03.jpg" height="30%" width="30%">
</LI>
<li> Red Panda <br>
<img Src="https://www.thoughtco.com/thmb/s-sGgR7zQSq2tZlZMlD7uuY81Gk=/7360x4912/filters:fill(auto,1)/happy-red-panda-171399380-5b574325c9e77c005b690b41.jpg" height="30%" width="30%">
 </LI>
<li> Himalayan Yak <br>
<img Src="http://www.silvertineranch.ca/uploads/5/9/4/9/5949047/1804496_3_orig.jpg" height="30%" width="30%">
</LI>
<li> Giant-panda <br> 
<img Src="http://www.xinhuanet.com/english/2019-12/06/138611350_15756361946211n.jpg" height="30%" width="30%">
</LI>
<li> Himalayan Marmot <br> 
<img Src="https://news.cgtn.com/news/3d3d514d7755444f31457a6333566d54/img/5bcc73138da34ec987d434f94e473892/5bcc73138da34ec987d434f94e473892.jpg" height="30%" width="30%">
</LI>


</ul>
```

here is the ss of the output

[image]

Comment: Please add your code and more explanation of what you want to happen. Note to add code you can use the curly bracket icon in the editor. However, it's more helpful if you could create an actual runnable snippet we can try for ourselves see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to explain your problem next time to let the other help you more.

Try this code maybe it's what you want, just adjust **width** / **height** of image and also **li**:

```css
  li {
      display:block;
      float:left;
      width:200px; /* adjust */
      padding: 5px; /*adjust*/
     }
```

```html
      <ul type="disc">

        <li><Img Src="http://www.shunya.net/Pictures/Himalayas/Darjeeling/HimalayanBear03.jpg" height="30%" width="30%"> <br> Himalayan/Indian Black Bear 
        
        </li>
        <li><img Src="https://www.thoughtco.com/thmb/s-sGgR7zQSq2tZlZMlD7uuY81Gk=/7360x4912/filters:fill(auto,1)/happy-red-panda-171399380-5b574325c9e77c005b690b41.jpg" height="30%" width="30%"> <br> Red Panda
        
        </li>
        <li> <img Src="http://www.silvertineranch.ca/uploads/5/9/4/9/5949047/1804496_3_orig.jpg" height="30%" width="30%"><br>Himalayan Yak 
        
        </li>
        <li> <img Src="http://www.xinhuanet.com/english/2019-12/06/138611350_15756361946211n.jpg" height="30%" width="30%"><br> Giant-panda 
        
        </li>
        <li> <img Src="https://news.cgtn.com/news/3d3d514d7755444f31457a6333566d54/img/5bcc73138da34ec987d434f94e473892/5bcc73138da34ec987d434f94e473892.jpg" height="30%" width="30%"><br>Himalayan Marmot  
        
        </li>
        
        
        </ul>
```